# Storing data for drawing graphs in iOS app

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm creating an iOS app that draws graphs. What's the easiest way of storing the data for drawing these graphs? I'm using GET requests to retrieve data from a server. The data is updated roughly every 15 mins. I need to be able to add the new data every 15 mins to the old data.

I've looked at using Core Data but not sure how to proceed as it appears there are multiple routes I can choose.

Some general pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Depends on what the data looks like. Please provide some more info on that

Comment: It's in a CSV format.

Comment: Do you want to store unlimited or is there some point where you want to delete 'old' data?

Comment: I'd like it to be unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the data to be persisted across runs of the app and have "unlimited" amount then you will want to use Core Data.  If you just need a little data during 1 run of the app you can use things like an NSArray of NSDictionary's.

Comment: Can I just use Core Data on it's own? Don't I need some sort of database like SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

The very very simplest way to save your data is as a plist. NSArray and NSDictionary both provide `-writeToFile:atomically:` and `-initWithContentsOfFile:`.

For any complicated retrieval or searching, you'll want to learn about and use Core Data. But for simply dumping the entire array out and getting it back, these methods suffice. You'll encounter memory pressure for large datasets, which is why Core Data has been suggested.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive graph data from server, do you receive delta change or complete set again?

In case its delta change, you should use NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary. Keep appending more records.

In case you receive full set, you should clear all objects in NSArray/NSDictionary and re populate with data received on server.

Core data is for persistent storage in file system. Based on your requirement it doesn't look like you need one.

Comment: But I need the data to be persistent. It has to be there every time I run the app as I want the user to be able to look at all the data to date. I don't want to fetch the data and redraw the graph every time, only the new data.

Comment: Well then, every time you receive data, you have to save it via core data. When you want to display, you have to display only what is fetched from core data. In short, web service data goes directly to database using core data and all the display stuff comes back from core data via fetch.